# Agora cloud recording not starting properly

Tags: amazon-s3, agora.io

I'm facing some issues in agora cloud recording with `amazon S3`. Not able to connect `s3` properly. Getting `404` error when running postman.

```
{
    "cname": "Stream-On",
    "uid": "527841",
    "clientRequest": {
        "token": "temp_token",
        "recordingConfig": {
            "maxIdleTime": 120,
            "streamTypes": 2,
            "audioProfile": 1,
            "channelType": 1,
            "videoStreamType": 0,
            "transcodingConfig": {
                "width": 360,
                "height": 640,
                "fps": 30,
                "bitrate": 600,
                "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
                "maxResolutionUid": "1"
            }
        },
        "storageConfig": {
            "vendor": 1,
            "region": 8,
            "bucket": "live-stream",
            "accessKey": "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "secretKey": "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to start my cloud recording I am receiving the `resourceId` and `sid` but and I try to stop it shows `Failed to find worker` and my amazon s3 bucket is also still empty

```
{
    "resourceId": "temp_resource_id",
    "code": 404,
    "serverResponse": {
        "command": "StopCloudRecorder",
        "payload": {
            "message": "Failed to find worker."
        },
        "subscribeModeBitmask": 1,
        "vid": "471258"
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you set the CORS policy on the bucket for the domain sending the request? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

Comment: I tried this but still, I'm facing the issue.
https://prnt.sc/22f14rp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a 404 response from `stop` means your original request for `start` was properly formatted and successfully making the call to start the Agora Cloud Recorder instance but something caused the Agora Cloud Recorder worker to fail to start, so when you call stop there is nothing to stop because nothing actually started.

[I wrote this quick-start guide on how to set up Cloud Recording](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708) and use the [Agora Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM) to test that your storage bucket is properly configured. I would recommend using it within Postman because it offers a working config that requires you to set your connection credentials into the variables and it should work if your bucket is properly configured.